# Rock, Paper, Scissors Java Programming Stuck

Tags: java

i'm new to Java Programming and I've looked through all the other questions and none of them seem to exactly help me with my dilemma. See, whenever I use my program all the answers show up and not just the right one. I don't know how to fix this. If anyone has advice please let me know. :) There is no computer in this, just two people or yourself. Thank you. I'm most likely overthinking this and it's going to end up being something very simple. haha.

```
      import java.util.*;

    public class RPS2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String p1;
        String p2;
        String user1 = "User 1";
        String user2 = "User 2";

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Player 1, please enter your choice [P/R/S]");
        p1 = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Player 2, please enter your choice [P/R/S]");
        p2 = keyboard.nextLine();

        if(user1.equalsIgnoreCase("p") && user2.equalsIgnoreCase("r"));
          System.out.println("Paper covers rock, Player 1 wins!");
        if(user1.equalsIgnoreCase("R") && user2.equalsIgnoreCase("S"));
          System.out.println("Paper covers rock, Player 2 wins!");

        if(user1.equalsIgnoreCase("p") && user2.equalsIgnoreCase("s"));
          System.out.println("Scissors cuts paper, Player 2 wins!");
        if(user1.equalsIgnoreCase("S") && user2.equalsIgnoreCase("P"));
          System.out.println("Scissors cuts paper, Player 1 wins!");

        if(user1.equalsIgnoreCase("r") && user2.equalsIgnoreCase("s"));
          System.out.println("Rock breaks scissors, Player 1 wins!");
        if(user1.equalsIgnoreCase("S") && user2.equalsIgnoreCase("R"));
          System.out.println("Rock breaks scissors, Player 2 wins!"); 

        if(user1.equalsIgnoreCase("user2"));
          System.out.println("Draw");
    }
}
```

Comment: When you get an answer, you should mark that answer as correct with the  tick mark... Not edit the question saying it was solved...

Answer (score 3):

You put the answers in `p1` and `p2` but then compare `user1` and `user2`. So you aren't actually comparing the user input.

And as @andreicovaciu points out, you have `;` after each `if` that you need to remove.

Answer (score 2):

You have a trailing `;` at the end of each of your `if` conditions...

```
if(user1.equalsIgnoreCase("p") && user2.equalsIgnoreCase("r"));
                                                    ----------^
```

This means that the statement is essentially closed (or does nothing) and the line immediately following will executed regardless

Good practice would recommend that you always surround your `if` conditions in `{...}`, for example...

```
if(user1.equalsIgnoreCase("p") && user2.equalsIgnoreCase("r")) {
    System.out.println("Paper covers rock, Player 1 wins!");
}
```

I would also use `if-else` statements

```
if(user1.equalsIgnoreCase("p") && user2.equalsIgnoreCase("r")) {
    System.out.println("Paper covers rock, Player 1 wins!");
} else if(user1.equalsIgnoreCase("R") && user2.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {
    System.out.println("Paper covers rock, Player 2 wins!");
} ...
```

This will further decrease the potential for you to accidentally have more then on win condition (but I would structure it differently, but that's just me ;))

You're also comparing the wrong values (thanks John3136 +1)

```
String p1;
String p2;
String user1 = "User 1";
String user2 = "User 2";
//...
System.out.println("Player 1, please enter your choice [P/R/S]");
p1 = keyboard.nextLine();
System.out.println("Player 2, please enter your choice [P/R/S]");
p2 = keyboard.nextLine();

 if(p1.equalsIgnoreCase("p") && p2.equalsIgnoreCase("r")) {
    System.out.println("Paper covers rock, Player 1 wins!");
} else if(p1.equalsIgnoreCase("R") && p2.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {
    System.out.println("Paper covers rock, Player 2 wins!");
} ...
```

Answer (score 0):

After each `if` you put there a semicolon

Answer (score 0):

All of your conditional lines have semicolons at the end

```
if(user1.equalsIgnoreCase("p") && user2.equalsIgnoreCase("r"));
```

remove the semicolons for all of them. I think that will fix.